# GitPython - Pull from all branches

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am setting up a script to update our local repositories and I have had to manually add the remote repository I would like to pull from (please see code below currently set to "Staging"). What would be a good way or best practice to pull from all remote repositories and not have to specify them individually?

Is there a wildcard to pull all such as:

```
repo.remotes.origin.pull(*)
```

Currently written as:

```
repo.remotes.origin.pull("Staging")
```

Comment: `pull` is `fetch` followed by `merge`. Think about that and then think about what you want this thing to do.

Comment: Appreciate the answer and after speaking with some of our Dev's it sounds like they would prefer the option to choose instead of doing all or some. Thank you again and now its time to pivot haha.